Convert WKB geometry to WKT
I am using DuckDB in order to access buildings polygons (an open dataset).
query = f"""
SELECT
    type,
    height,
    level,
    class,
    JSON(names) as names,
    JSON(sources) as sources,
    ST_GeomFromWKB(geometry) as geometry

FROM
    read_parquet('s3://overturemaps-us-west-2/release/2024-03-12-alpha.0/theme=buildings/type=*/*', hive_partitioning=1)
LIMIT 100
"""

df = duckdb.sql(query).to_df()

I am trying to get the geometry (polygons) of the buildings, however, when I check the dataframe, the geometry column looks like this:

when I print the first geometry, it is in a bytearray form:
df['geometry'][0]
>>>bytearray(b"\x02\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00of\'\xc3\xcfL\xa7\xc2\\f\'\xc3\....

my question is how can I convert it to WKT? I was trying solutions like to_wkt (fails because  I couldn't set the geometry column to geometry type as it has invalid geometry type), from_wkb (same issue).
My end goal is to translate this geometry into wkt.

If you do not need them as actual geometries, just add ST_AsText(...) to your query:
query = f"""
SELECT
    type,
    height,
    level,
    class,
    JSON(names) as names,
    JSON(sources) as sources,
    ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromWKB(geometry)) as geometry

FROM
    read_parquet('s3://overturemaps-us-west-2/release/2024-03-12-alpha.0/theme=buildings/type=*/*', hive_partitioning=1)
LIMIT 100
"""

df = duckdb.sql(query).to_df()

